# Remove/create individual styling from a view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view

I have a rails app with about 20 views. On 15 of those views I want to the same style to be reflected - Navbar on top, same buttons, etc. Right now, that's what I have.

However, on the other 5 views I want a specific style that is different than the above. Right now, when I create a new view, each view has the same style as the other 15. I'm assuming this is because my `application.html.erb` file contains that specific styling.

How can I create a custom layout for a specific view/set of views that is totally different than the majority? It looks like the custom styles are being referenced from `app/views/layouts`, but if that's the case what naming convention do I use to create a new layout and how do I refer to that layout from my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is in the controller. You can create a new layout called `custom_layout.erb` in `app/views/layouts` and then in your controller, you can reference the layout in the action

```
def show
 render layout: "custom_layout"
end
```

Or for the whole controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "custom_layout"

  def show
  end
end
```

Check out the [Rails Guide - Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) Sections 2.2.11.2 and 2.2.12 for more examples

Hope this helps

Comment: Absolutely - Thanks, I'll check out the guide and use what you've got here to get started.